# Flex issue with Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I have set up a codepen here https://codepen.io/Lewy_H/pen/ZKBzBx.

I am getting strange behaviour in Firefox and IE but it works fine in Chrome as that was the browser I designed it in. The issue should be obvious at first glance but the internal boxes are misaligned - to the left in Firefox and to the right in IE. In addition, the icons don't even load in IE.

Could anybody shed some light on the issue? Am I just going about this in completely the wrong way?

Full code show below:

**HTML**

```
<section class="section section-default mt-none mb-none section-services">
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="mb-sm">
      Our <strong>Services</strong>
   </h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
<div class="service-block-container">
<div class="service-block">
<div class="service-underlay">
<span class="service-name">
Web Applications
</span>
<a class="cta" href="/services/web-applications">Learn More</a>
</div>
<span class="service-icon">
<em class="fa fa-code"></em>
</span>
<span class="service-desc">
Bespoke web applications for end to end solutions
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
<div class="service-block-container">
<div class="service-block">
<div class="service-underlay">
<span class="service-name">
ERP
</span>
<a class="cta" href="/services/enterprise-resource-planning">Learn More</a>
</div>
<span class="service-icon">
<em class="fa fa-barcode"></em>
</span>
<span class="service-desc">
World leading enterprise resource planning software
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
<div class="service-block-container">
<div class="service-block">
<div class="service-underlay">
<span class="service-name">
Accounting Solutions
</span>
<a class="cta" href="/services/accounting-solutions">Learn More</a>
</div>
<span class="service-icon">
<em class="fa fa-gbp"></em>
</span>
<span class="service-desc">
Installation and support of Sage and Pegasus Opera
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
<div class="service-block-container">
<div class="service-block">
<div class="service-underlay">
<span class="service-name">
Support Solutions
</span>
<a class="cta" href="/services/support-solutions">Learn More</a>
</div>
<span class="service-icon">
<em class="fa fa-support"></em>
</span>
<span class="service-desc">
Maintenance and support of infrastructure
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
<div class="service-block-container">
<div class="service-block">
<div class="service-underlay">
<span class="service-name">
Bespoke Solutions
</span>
<a class="cta" href="/services/bespoke-solutions">Learn More</a>
</div>
<span class="service-icon">
<em class="fa fa-cogs"></em>
</span>
<span class="service-desc">
Creative solutions to make your job easier
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
<div class="service-block-container">
<div class="service-block">
<div class="service-underlay">
<span class="service-name">
Infrastructure Planning
</span>
<a class="cta" href="/services/infrastructure-planning">Learn More</a>
</div>
<span class="service-icon">
<em class="fa fa-pie-chart"></em>
</span>
<span class="service-desc">
Communications and networking made simple
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.service-block-container {
  display:flex;  
  justify-content: center;
}

.service-block {
  min-width:180px;
  width:180px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;  
  justify-content: center;
   text-align:center;
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#666;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:30px;
   padding:0 10px;
}

.service-underlay {
  height:60px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  padding-top: 18px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.service-icon {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    color: #737373;
}

.service-name {
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
   text-transform: Capitalize;
}

.service-desc {
  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-top: 75px
}

.service-underlay .cta {
  margin-top:115px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.service-block:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid #141b41;
}

.service-block:hover .service-underlay{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #141b41;
}

.service-block:hover .service-icon {
  color:#fff;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  top:80px;
}

.service-block:hover .service-name {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.service-block:hover .service-desc {
  display:none;
}

.service-block .service-underlay .cta:hover {  
  text-decoration:none;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with the absolute positioning of the service-icon and service-underlay classes. After adding`left:0; right:0;` the items were correctly centered in all browsers.

The icon issue was with my IE privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

I added `left: auto;` to your `.service-icon` styles and it seems to fix the issue on Firefox (as I'm on Mac I can't test for IE). The icon is probably offset because it doesn't compute the default `left` value the same way Chrome does.

Also, do yourself a favour and indent your code. CodePen does it for you in the options for HTML > Tidy HTML.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I added `left: 0;` to the service-underlay class and that has fixed the underlay alignment issue but the issue with the icon still persists even after I added `left:auto` as you suggested; not at first, but after you trigger the CSS transition.

Comment: Indeed it does. Then I suggest, since you're using absolute positioning, that you add `left: 50%;` and correctly place it in the centre using `transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1);`. Also remember to use `transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1.5);` on the relevant hover rule.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have found the solution now. I needed to add `left:0; right:0;` to the .service-icon and .service-underlay classes - this allows it to work with flex without the hacks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!